# Updating favorite/ignored tags on tagged questions page messes up formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, tag-watching

When I go to the [tagged questions page for Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), I notice that SO will not highlight questions that only match my favorited [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) tag:

[image: Questions tagged with Symfony; note that question that only matches my favorited symfony tag is not highlighted (the other questions match at least one other favorited tag).]

So far so good.  But look what happens when I updated my favorite and/or ignored tags:

[image: Same page as above, but now everything is highlighted.]

Now everything is highlighted (unless it matches an ignored tag).

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the supposedly fixed [Favorite tagged questions highlighted when they shouldn't (after new activity rolldown)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125595/33732).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this myself, and was glad I wasn't the only one who had stumbled upon this great injustice.

Updating `applyPrefs()` in `StackExchange.tagPreferences` to remember what's passed to it the first time should fix that, I suppose, since the page invokes it with the list of tags that should be excluded from matching in the first place:

```
var tagged;
// ...
function applyPrefs(c, ignore) {
    if (tagged === undefined) {
        tagged = ignore || false;
    } else if (tagged) {
        // Probably can reduce this to just an assignment if !ignore,
        // since ignore will likely only be provided on the first call
        ignore = ignore ? Array.prototype.push.apply(ignore, tagged) : tagged;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The minimized function `c` could also be updated to parse tags out of the search URL, but because the site apparently also avoids highlighting searched-for favourite tags on normal searches now, this option would be a bit of a pain. For just the `/questions/tagged/` case though, that'd look something like this:

```
// ...
g || e(d, $(c).text());

var tagged = null;

if (/^\/questions\/tagged\//.test(location.pathname)) {
    tagged = decodeURIComponent(location.pathname.substring(
        '/questions/tagged/'.length
    ).replace('+', ' ')).split(' ');
}

applyPrefs(false, tagged);
```

However, I think there are too many nuances about the unaccounted for `/search?q=` case to make this the more attractive solution.