# Favorite tagged questions highlighted when they shouldn't (after new activity rolldown)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

With the new rolldown-questions-with-new-activity feature, if you are looking only at questions tagged with one of your favorite tag all new and old questions got highlighted when (I think) none of them shouldn't.

This is what I saw after ckicking to roll down *questions with new activity*:

[image: highlighted questions]

The snapshout is only of the top part of the page, but **all** the questions are highlighted.

After a refresh of the page this is what it looks like (and how it should be):

[image: normal view]

I don't think that this behaviour was a design choice since having everything highlighted is like no highlighting at all, so I'm reporting this as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag highlighting for realtime updates will follow the same pattern as it does normally while on the tag page after the next deploy.

Comment: Has the next deploy happened yet? I still see this behavior on the `c++` tag (but not the `delphi` or `perl` tags).