# All posts get highlighted when adding a favourite tag from its tag page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-watching

If you go to a tag page that isn't already your favourite, then make that tag a favourite tag all posts on the page get highlighted.

This doesn't happen in the normal case of viewing a tag page of an already-favourited tag.

The behaviour should be the same regardless of whether you already have the tag favourited, or you're just adding it from the tag page.

---

To observe:

1. Go to the tag page of a tag you don't have favourited.
2. Add that tag to your favourites (I did this by hovering on the tag then clicking the star).
3. Observe all tags being highlighted as you do this. (Incorrect behaviour).
4. Refresh the page to observe correct highlighting.
5. Unfavourite the tag.

Comment: Think this is related and/or duplicate (but it's early, so I'm not positive): [Updating favorite/ignored tags on tagged questions page messes up formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116030)

Comment: You're right (I think); that's describing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

We send down a list of "shouldn't be highlighted" tags when rendering a tag-list page, but that particular path wasn't respecting (or even looking at, really) that list when adding new favorites.